# Is "during cold weather" a prepositional phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

In the following sentence is *during cold weather* a prepositional phrase?

> It has a very robust flavor and is traditionally consumed **during cold weather**.

Comment: [For, During, and While are three of the most common prepositions used in time expressions](https://continuingstudies.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/490/grammar/prepositions-time-for-during-while/)

Comment: Hi! Please edit to tell a bit about why you had doubts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *during cold weather* is a preposition phrase.  Similar examples are shown below.

[During](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/during#google_vignette)

> preposition (THROUGH)
> A2

> from the beginning to the end of a particular period:
> They work **during the night** and sleep by day.
> There were huge advances in aviation technology **during the Second World War**.

A preposition with its complement, in this case, *cold weather* forms a preposition phrase.

Comment: +1 Perfect answer.